# List adding how its work in this specify example Java

Tags: java

I have stack on my jee application
Abort of action id .. invoked while multiple threads active within it

Debuger stoped on list action

```
For(Object obj : ExampleData.getOneofDate())
 { ExampleData aData = (ExampleDate) obj

List<DataRelated> aDataRelated=
                    aDataDAO.loadbyID(aData.get().getDirection().getID(), Year);
}
```

And how its look loadbyID

```
 return query().
                    eagerFetch("linkedExample").
                      eagerFetch("linkedExample.case").
                    whereEquals("direction.id", aIdDzialki).
                    list();
```

When list of OneofData is short all working fine, by when list have 20-30 throw exception. A haven't idea why , and how I can change code. 
Please help me tell me what can i try change?

StackTrace

```
    10:57:47,188 WARN  [arjuna] ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a162089:7eac3d1b:56c762bf:348 in state  RUN
10:57:47,455 WARN  [arjuna] ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a162089:7eac3d1b:56c762bf:348 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
10:57:47,456 WARN  [arjuna] ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0a162089:7eac3d1b:56c762bf:348 aborting with 1 threads active!
10:57:47,457 WARN  [SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
10:57:47,459 WARN  [arjuna] ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff0a162089:7eac3d1b:56c762bf:348
10:57:47,464 ERROR [ejb3] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
```

Comment: what is the exception? Please post the stacktrace

Comment: added the head part of stacktrace